# Python month start and end dates between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, python-datetime

I need to have each month start and end dates between two dates. Presently, I am creating the list manually each time I need it.

```
start = 2019-10-01
end = today
```

Expected output:

```
start_times = ['10/1/2019 05:00:00 AM','11/1/2019 05:00:00 AM','12/1/2019 05:00:00 AM','1/1/2020 05:00:00 AM','2/1/2020 05:00:00 AM','3/1/2020 05:00:00 AM'+'4/1/2020 05:00:00 AM','5/1/2020 05:00:00 AM','6/1/2020 05:00:00 AM','7/1/2020 05:00:00 AM','8/1/2020 05:00:00 AM']
end_times = ['10/31/2019 08:00:00 PM','11/30/2019 08:00:00 PM','12/31/2019 08:00:00 PM','1/31/2020 08:00:00 PM','2/29/2020 08:00:00 PM','3/31/2020 08:00:00 PM','4/30/2020 08:00:00 PM','5/31/2020 08:00:00 PM','6/30/2020 08:00:00 PM','7/31/2020 08:00:00 PM','8/31/2020 08:00:00 PM']
```

Any idea on how to proceed here.

Comment: where does 5 AM and 8 PM come from?

Comment: The rest of the program requires the dates to be in this format to run. Otherwise raises error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need a date range and specific formatting I would suggest using numpy for date range creation and calculations then use python datetime to format like this:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

def dateRange(start='2019-10-01', end='2020-08-28'):
    
    start_date = np.datetime64(start[:-3])  
    #Add one month to end date so last month is included
    end_date = np.datetime64(end[:-3]) + np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
    #Create Date Range
    date_range = np.arange(start_date, end_date, dtype='datetime64[M]')
    #Add 5 AM to start_dates
    start_dates = date_range + np.timedelta64(5, 'h')
    #Add 1 Month and subrtract 4 hours to 8 PM on last day of month
    end_dates = date_range + np.timedelta64(1, 'M') - np.timedelta64(4, 'h')
    #Apply Formatting   
    final_start_dates = [parse_date(np.datetime_as_string(d, unit='s')) for d in start_dates]
    final_end_dates = [parse_date(np.datetime_as_string(d, unit='s')) for d in end_dates]
    
    return final_start_dates, final_end_dates

def parse_date(date_string):
    #parse numpy date string
    date_time = date_string.split('T')
    date_parts = date_time[0].split('-')
    time_parts = date_time[1][:-1].split(':')
    #convert string values to ints
    datetime_ints = [int(d) for d in date_parts] + [int(time_parts[0])]
    
    #apply formatting
    return dt.datetime(*datetime_ints).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Output:

```
>>> start,end=dateRange()
>>> start
['10/01/2019 05:00:00 AM', '11/01/2019 05:00:00 AM', '12/01/2019 05:00:00 AM', '01/01/2020 05:00:00 AM', '02/01/2020 05:00:00 AM', '03/01/2020 05:00:00 AM', '04/01/2020 05:00:00 AM', '05/01/2020 05:00:00 AM', '06/01/2020 05:00:00 AM', '07/01/2020 05:00:00 AM', '08/01/2020 05:00:00 AM']
>>> end
['10/31/2019 08:00:00 PM', '11/30/2019 08:00:00 PM', '12/31/2019 08:00:00 PM', '01/31/2020 08:00:00 PM', '02/29/2020 08:00:00 PM', '03/31/2020 08:00:00 PM', '04/30/2020 08:00:00 PM', '05/31/2020 08:00:00 PM', '06/30/2020 08:00:00 PM', '07/31/2020 08:00:00 PM', '08/31/2020 08:00:00 PM']
```

I think this is what you are looking for with your question on producing each day. It is actually easier.

```
def all_dates(start='2019-10-01', end='2019-10-15'):
    
    start_date = np.datetime64(start)   
    #Add one day to end date so last say is included
    end_date = np.datetime64(end) + np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    #Create Date Range
    date_range = np.arange(start_date, end_date, dtype='datetime64[D]')
    
    final_start_dates = [parse_date(np.datetime_as_string(d + np.timedelta64(5, 'h'), unit='s')) for d in date_range]
    
    final_end_dates = [parse_date(np.datetime_as_string(d + np.timedelta64(20, 'h'), unit='s')) for d in date_range]
    
    return final_start_dates, final_end_dates
```

Output:

```
>>> start, end = all_dates()
>>> start
['10/1/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/2/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/3/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/4/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/5/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/6/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/7/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/8/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/9/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/10/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/11/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/12/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/13/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/14/2019 05:00:00 AM', '10/15/2019 05:00:00 AM']
>>> end
['10/1/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/2/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/3/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/4/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/5/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/6/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/7/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/8/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/9/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/10/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/11/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/12/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/13/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/14/2019 08:00:00 PM', '10/15/2019 08:00:00 PM']
```

Comment: I have a question. Now I want to produce each day with 5 AM and 8 PM timings. How do I get it?

Comment: Thanks. I actually modified your original code to produce either month or day dates based on the requirement. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The last day will be the first day of next month minus 1.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start = datetime(year = 2020, month = 5, day = 16)

start_times = datetime(year = start.year, month = start.month, day = 1)

if start.month == 12:
    end_times = datetime(year = start.year + 1, month = 1, day = 1) - timedelta(days = 1)
else:
    end_times = datetime(year = start.year, month = start.month + 1, day = 1) - timedelta(days = 1)
    
print(start_times)
print(end_times)
```

output:

```
2020-05-01 00:00:00
2020-05-31 00:00:00
```